# Can't ping into subnet

Tags: subnet

I am currently setting up a network and I'm having some pinging issues between computers, how could I fix this ?

Computer A, which is in the main network can ping his own router, and the subnet router, but not Computer B which is inside the subnet.

> ping 192.168.98.100 is failing

Computer B, on his side, can ping Computer A.

> ping 192.168.99.101 is fine

The main router is a cisco rv160w and the subnet router is a cisco rv130w

I have set a route in the main router, and I think that is where the issue is

```
Network      | Mask          | Next hop
192.168.98.0 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.99.52
```

Both network and subnet are open to wan request

[Network description with IP address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdVRo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is not usual to have 192.168.99.0 on different interfaces. Choose another numbers for the internal networks.

Comment: i dont see an gateway set nor a route that tell 98 to route to 99?